# Why cant I get the value of key into my string, it keeps taking the value +key+

Tags: javascript, html, json, django

I'm trying to create a html table using javascript. I'm trying to add data to the table and some of the data are URL links. I'm trying to concatenate the links with variables but instead of the variable value in the String I,m getting a +key+ value. Could someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong please

javascript below

```
function populateTable(){
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    $("#stats tr").remove();
    var table_data ='';

    for (var key in data){
      table_data += '<tr>';
      table_data += '<td><a href = "{% url 'webapp-graphv2' '+key+'%}">Link</a></td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +key+ '</td>'
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.PRICE+ '</td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.HIGHDAY+ '</td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.LOWDAY+ '</td>';
      table_data += '<td>' +data[key].EUR.MKTCAP+ '</td>';

      if (data[key].EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR[0] == '-') {
        table_data += '<td style = "color:red">' +data[key].EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR+ '</td>';
      } else {
        table_data += '<td style = "color:green">' +data[key].EUR.CHANGEPCT24HOUR+ '</td>';
      }
      table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#stats').append(table_data);
    },
  })
  setTimeout(populateTable,1000);
}
```

Where I think the error is below

```
table_data += '<td><a href = "{% url 'webapp-graphv2' '+key+'%}">Link</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
table_data += '<td><a href = "{% url \'webapp-graphv2\' '+key+'%}">Link</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes surrounding `webapp-graphv2`:

```
table_data += '<td><a href = "{% url \'webapp-graphv2\' ' + key + '%}">Link</a></td>';
```

Alternatively, use a template literal for the full string:

```
table_data += `<td><a href = "{% url 'webapp-graphv2' ${key} %}">Link</a></td>`;
```

Comment: the template string should probably look like:
`table_data += \`<td><a href = "{% url 'webapp-graphv2' '${key}'%}">Link</a></td>\`;`

Comment: My bad, fixed @0xnoob.

Answer (score 0):

try `table_data += '<td><a href = "{% url \'webapp-graphv2\' '+key+'%}">Link</a></td>';` instead.  You were escaping your outermost `'`.

To avoid these kind of issues you can also concatenate string in JavaScript like:

```
table_data += `<td><a href = "{% url 'webapp-graphv2' '${key}'%}">Link</a></td>`
```

Using `${var}` inside of backticks `` `${var}` `` injects the variable without using `'` or `"`.